# Changing results in the debugger

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am trying to fix a bug in an iPhone app, and find myself in front of this situation.
The instance variable myView is of type MYTextView, and MYTextView is a subclass of UITextView.

At the debugger I enter a few times in a row: p myView.text
the strange thing, as one can see below, is that I get different results:

```
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $34 = 0x095da870 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
05"
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $35 = 0x0a2c5620 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
"
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $36 = 0x09515f60 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
щ"
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $37 = 0x09515f80 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
㏀ड़ख़筀ज़툠ज़梐
⨈Ⴊ"
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $38 = 0x0a2c3800 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
妜샷फ़"
(lldb) p myView.text
(NSString *) $39 = 0x095e7010 @"พี(the-date-in-Thai-Language)
"
```

Above the results $35 and $39 contain what I expect, the other lines contain garbage at the end of the expect string.

I don't understand how this changing garbage can be here, when I am supposed to be inside the debugger an pausing.
One more thing is that I am having this kind of problem only with the Thai language.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the data formatter for NSString.
Are you on Xcode 4.6? If so I would love it if you filed a bug against Xcode with as much context as possible.
My guess is that there is some buffer that is not being managed properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `p` command, there are several different things lldb can do.

For simple concrete types (`int`, `int *`) it may only print the value in the variable (10, 0xffffffff83021600).  It may have a formatter preference set (e.g. display the `int` in hexadecimal).  It may have a more sophisticated python formatter (which can read different parts of memory and present a high-level view of the object to you).  Finally, it may actually run code in your program to come up with a high level view of that variable.

In this case, with Xcode 4.6, this looks like a simple `NSString` ivar and so the expectation is that lldb can use its built-in python formatter for NSString objects.  This built-in formatter looks at the object memory and knows how to reconstruct the actual string for display without running any code in your program.  In which case, the content of the string should not be modified.

Earlier versions (and gdb) may run code in your program to format the string, and it is possible that the program could change a little in the process.  There is a lot of work done to ensure that doesn't happen, but the possibility exists.

Enrico is suspecting that the built-in python formatter function for `NSString` may be misbehaving somehow in your program and providing string summaries that change as you re-call the formatter.  Please do file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ with the details for how to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: In this case, the best is for me to make a tiny program to make it simple to explain. And easy for the people reading as well.

Comment: I followed the above advice, by building a sample project, and making a bug report.

Comment: great!  That's the best way to ensure it gets fixed -- I don't think anyone else has hit this particular problem.